# Can I use QAbstractListModel with QTreeView (hierarchy)?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

Is it possible to use `QAbstractListModel` for a **hierarchical** `QTreeView`? I want to make very clear, that I am talking about a tree view **with an expandable / collapsible hierarchy**.

From the examples it seems **not** to be recommended, but is is possible (means stable + feasible)? The [tutorial here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html) shows an overview (at the bottom), which always uses `QStandardItemModel` for tree views.

I wonder what really makes the data appearing in a hierarchy? So far I can identify the following functions:

1. data
2. row count
3. column count
4. hasChildren

I wonder if it is possible to "fake" a hierarchy by applying the corresponding logic there. Or would this be a complete mess? Is there any example doing so (using `QAbstractListModel` for a hierarchy)

Comment: Straight from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#details): `Since the model provides a more specialized interface than QAbstractItemModel, it is not suitable for use with tree views; you will need to subclass QAbstractItemModel if you want to provide a model for that purpose.`  The whole point is a list model is simple because it only allows one column.  What is your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Mistake on my side. Thanks for your hint. Please provide your comment as answer, I will accept and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Retired Ninja:

Straight from the documentation: Since the model provides a more specialized interface than `QAbstractItemModel`, it is not suitable for use with tree views;